# RecyclerView Adapter OnClickListener crashes: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I am new to Android Studio and starting learning via a project of mine. I realize this question has been asked so many times over the last years but I have read most of them and could not fix my code.

The idea is to parse a list from an online JSON file and make clickable cards that take the user to the associated link.

I managed to get the cards on screen but the app crashes the moment the card is clicked. I also (think that I) understand that this problem could arise when I use a secondary layout xml and the objects are in the wrong place.

My MainActivity.java: (you might see some variable names are off-topic, I am using a template to get my first project running)

```
package net.smallacademy.songslist;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<Song> songs;
    private static String JSON_URL = "JSON LINK";
    Adapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.songsList);
        songs = new ArrayList<>();
        extractSongs();
    }

    private void extractSongs() {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, JSON_URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject songObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

                        Song song = new Song();
                        song.setTitle(songObject.getString("title").toString());
                        song.setLink(songObject.getString("link"));
                        song.setJournal(songObject.getString("journal".toString()));
                        song.setDate(songObject.getString("date"));
                        songs.add(song);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
                adapter = new Adapter(getApplicationContext(),songs);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("tag", "onErrorResponse: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        });

        queue.add(jsonArrayRequest);

    }
}
```

My Adapter.java:

```
package net.smallacademy.songslist;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.List;

public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<Song> songs;

    Context context;

    public Adapter(Context ctx, List<Song> songs){
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
        this.songs = songs;

        this.context = ctx;

    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_layout,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        // bind the data
        holder.artTitle.setText(songs.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.artJournal.setText(songs.get(position).getJournal());
        holder.artDate.setText(songs.get(position).getDate());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return songs.size();
    }

    public  class ViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView artTitle,artJournal,artDate,artLink;
        Button buttonVisit;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            artTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.artTitle);
            artJournal = itemView.findViewById(R.id.artJournal);
            artDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.artDate);

            // handle onClick

            artTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

My activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/songsList"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and my custom layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/artDate"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="DATE"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/artTitle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="ARTICLE TITLE"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/artDate" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/artJournal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:text="Journal Name"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/artTitle" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and the stack trace:

```
    android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
        at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:952)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:928)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:383)
        at net.smallacademy.songslist.Adapter$ViewHolder$1.onClick(Adapter.java:81)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

I placed www.google.com as a placeholder link. I need to get each associated link from the JSON file.

I'd be happy if you could point me in the right direction.

Comment: You should start from reading the stacktrace

Comment: From the title I assume your application crashes and displays a stacktrace in Android Studio. It would be nice to see it.

Comment: What error do you receive exactly? Many small things can go wrong with this.

Comment: I have now included the stacktrace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work around the issue by passing the flag as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61892903/208273) says, but that will have undesired side effects when it comes to your back stack and multitasking.  The actual root cause of your problem is that you're using passing `getApplicationContext()` to your Adapter when you should be passing your `Activity`:

```java
adapter = new Adapter(getApplicationContext(),songs);
```

You should replace the above line with:

```java
adapter = new Adapter(MainActivity.this,songs);
```

Comment: This is what I head meant when I wrote that I read about memory issues with added flags. Your suggestion works smoothly, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a flag to your intent. You can check which one from the stacktrace.

```
artTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent);
```

Here is the Flag

```
 android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the **FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK** flag. Is this really what you want?
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. This does fix the app from crashing. But I have one question and please don't get me wrong I have about one week of AndroidStudio experience. From what I have read this type of approach is not recommended and is heavy on memory. Would you agree?

Comment: @new2linux Haven't heard anything like that. Also are you looking for an alternative to adding the flags to the intent? Also do you want to same url to open for every button?

Comment: I was looking into how to load different urls for each card. I need to read the url from json and pass that to onClickListener for each card.

Comment: Yes, you have assisted greatly. The code works in onBindViewholder.

Comment: This makes the crash go away, but doesn't solve the root cause.  See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/61906474/208273